# python tkinter import csv data to OptionMenu

Tags: python, list, csv, tkinter, optionmenu

I want to fill some `OptionMenu`'s with data I have previously scraped from a url.

Ex:

```
    with open('clubs.csv', newline ='') as club:
    reader=csv.reader(club)
    dummy_club = []
    dummy_club.extend(reader)
```

Later I want to use this in one of my `OptionMenu`s

Ex:

```
sv_club = StringVar()    
d_club = OptionMenu(app,variable=sv_club,value=dummy_club)
```

Unfortunately the list of around 700 items is put all in one row/line like when I click on my d_club `OptionMenu` on this screenshot:
[image]

Any Idea how I need to chance the code that after each item there will be a new row?

When I directly import my scraped data as a list into my `OptionMenu` it looks perfect.
But when I try to import the in .csv saved data when I start my GUI (so when I call `app.mainloop()`) it is messed up.

**EDIT:**

added code I use with my scraper, to get the .csv file:

```
def scrape():
    li_clubs = []
    print('getting clubs...\n')
    #click the dropdown menue to open the folder
    club_dropdown_menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/section/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[8]/div')
    club_dropdown_menu.click()
    time.sleep(1)

    # scrape all text
    scrape_clubs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='with-icon' and contains(text(), '')]")
    for club in scrape_clubs:
        export_clubs = club.text
        export_clubs = str(export_clubs)
        export_clubs = export_clubs.replace(',', '')
        li_clubs.append(export_clubs)
        
    m_club = d_club.children['menu']
    for val in li_clubs:
        m_club.add_command(label=val,command=lambda v=sv_club,l=val:v.set(l))

    with open('clubs.csv', 'w', newline='') as club:
        writer = csv.writer(club, quotechar=None)
        for i in li_clubs:
            writer.writerow(i.split(','))
```

The code is build like that, so that I can update the OptionMenu's if I need to.
The funcion `def scrape():` is bound to a button. So that when I press the utton, I do a scrape and update my optionMenu.

After that I write the list `li_clubs` into a `clubs.csv`file.

Because the data I need doesn't change very often, I have bound the **scrape** to a button so I can push it if I need.

But I want to load the data from the .csv file into my OptionMenu after each start. So that I can use the **scraped** data directly.

Comment: Can you include some code related?

Comment: not sure what code u mean? 
I aded my scraper code and more explanation of my code.

Comment: Try `dummy_club = [x[0] for x in reader]`, then `d_club = tk.OptionMenu(app, sv_club, *dummy_club)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the expansion/unpack/splat operator `*`. However, since the data is a list of lists (or tuple of tuples) you need to convert the inner lists to strings before doing so since the option menu requires a list of strings.

It might look something like this:

```
dummy_club = [" ".join(row) for row in dummy_club]
d_club = OptionMenu(app, sv_club, *dummy_club)
```

Though, an OptionMenu with 700 values will be very difficult to use. You should probably consider a ttk Combobox widget.

Comment: the advice with `*dummy_club` helped. Now all shown in one column and 700 rows.
But they are still in brackets `{}` 
Is there something else I need to add in the `reader` block to get rid of them?

Comment: @exec85 Maybe try indexing?

Comment: @CoolCloud maybe I should add that I am total beginner in coding. Could you please help me out what "indexing" would mean in my case?

Comment: What happens if you `print(*dummy_club)` ?  Does that have the curly brackets?  it may just be that your data comes with them.  In which case you will need to strip them off first.

Comment: @exec85 give `*dummy_club[0]` a try? not sure, it might just take the first element, or even throw a `IndexError`

Comment: @Cool Cloud I think the problem is, as long as the club names stored in the csv consist of only one word - there are no brackets. But as soon as there are more than one words it is put into {}. For example: {Bayern Munich} and if one word: Dortmund

Comment: @exec85 is it so? i dont have data, maybe its true, im not sure, though, instead just use a `Combobox`, life will be a lot easier, it looks modern too

Comment: @exec85 If they are in brackets, that means you have a list of lists rather than a list. You need to convert each inner list/tuple to a string.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley they are in Curley Brackets

Comment: @CoolCloud if I see it right it uses ttk. So I would have to re-code all my GUI to ttk?

Comment: @exec85: the data isn't in curly braces. The curly braces get added because you're passing a list of lists to `OptionMenu` rather than a list of strings. The `OptionMenu` requires a list of strings.

Comment: @exec85: switching to the ttk optionmenu won't change anything with respect to this problem. The problem is that you're passing a list of lists when the `OptionMenu` for both tk and ttk require a list of strings.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, Could you please help me to get the code changed to use combobox? I am using a StringVar and a callback function to update my OptionMenus AFTER I launched app.mainloop and after Inscraped all data.

I can't get this transferred to meet the Combobox method.